# Как в Телеграм боте сохранить ответ пользователя на /команду?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

Функция с которой связан вопрос:

```
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, Updater

def sku(update, context):
    chat = update.effective_chat
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat.id,
        text='Спрашивает информацию у пользователя'
    )
    # здесь нужно получить и сохранить в переменную ответ пользователя

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('sku', sku))
```

Comment: По-моему, метка неправильная... Код похож на python-telegram-bot, а pytelegrambotapi - другая библиотека

Comment: изначально была метка python-telegram-bot, а сейчас уже изменили(

Comment: Похоже на машину состояний, я подобное интереса ради делал через `user_data`: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c074fad12652ee18f3f697280942021983f1a49a/telegram_bot_examples/questionnaire__anketa__user_data.py, в самой библиотеке есть ConversationHandler, но мне с ним было непросто - есть ограничения и сложный он - https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/c074fad12652ee18f3f697280942021983f1a49a/telegram_bot_examples/questionnaire__anketa__ConversationHandler.py

Comment: спасибо за ответ, сейчас буду разбираться, надеюсь смогу сделать через user_data, а то ConversationHandler и правда пока сложноват для меня)